# How to delete my avatar in WTelegramClient

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-api, wtelegramclient

Currently, I am using [WTelegramClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WTelegramClient/) library on C#; how can I delete my telegram account avatar?

Answer (score 1):

Easy:

```
await client.Photos_UpdateProfilePhoto(null);
```

*(a `null` InputPhoto means [inputPhotoEmpty](https://corefork.telegram.org/constructor/inputPhotoEmpty))*

Comment: Thank you, and can you say how to use Photos_DeletePhotos() method?